# Clock markings refactoring for enhancement opportunities

Tags: python

The given Python code snippet is for drawing clock markings.

```py
from waffle_oak_clock import markings_number, markings_radius, markings_hours_size, markings_hours_color, markings_minutes_size, markings_minutes_color, clock

def draw_markings() -> None:
    ''' Draws the markings of the clock '''
    for i in range(markings_number):
        angle = radians(i * 360 / markings_number)
        x = markings_radius * sin(angle)
        y = -markings_radius * cos(angle)
  
    if i % 5 == 0:
        # Larger dot for hours
        clock.penup()
        clock.goto(x, y)
        clock.dot(markings_hours_size, markings_hours_color)
    elif i % 1 == 0:
        # Smaller dot for minutes
        clock.penup()
        clock.goto(x, y)
        clock.dot(markings_minutes_size, markings_minutes_color)
```

Are there opportunities for refactoring `draw_markings()` to enhance code readability and function?

This is the current, updated code:

```py
from math import sin, cos

def main(
    markings_radius: int = 220,
    markings_number: int = 60,
    markings_hours_color: str = "blue",
    markings_hours_size: int = 10,
    markings_minutes_color: str = "green",
    markings_minutes_size: int = 5,
):

    # Create a turtle to draw the markings
    clock = RawTurtle(screen)
    clock.speed(100)

    def draw_markings() -> None:
        """Draws the markings of the clock."""
        for minute in range(markings_number):
            angle = radians(minute * 360 / markings_number)
            x = markings_radius * sin(angle)
            y = -markings_radius * cos(angle)

        clock.penup()
        clock.goto(x, y)
        if minute % 5 == 0:
            clock.dot(markings_hours_size, markings_hours_color)
        else:
            clock.dot(markings_minutes_size, markings_minutes_color)
```

[This is the main app](https://github.com/attilavjda/waffle-oak-clock)

Comment: Is your indentation correct?

Comment: @Booboo I think so.

Comment: The code block beginning `if i % 5 == 0:` is not within the previous `for` loop and I thought perhaps it should be.

Comment: `elif i % 1 == 0` would be equivalent to `elif True`, which is better expressed as `else:`. This is because `i % 1` is always 0 for any integer `i`.

Comment: @Booboo, you are right, thank you. I can see the indentation now. I refactored the the condition to `else:` and wrote `clock.penup()` and `clock.goto(x, y)` outside the `if` `else` statement. Should I edit the question with the refactored function?

Comment: On this site only correct code that you wish reviewed should be posted. So I would say, "Yes!"

Comment: Thank you @Booboo, I updated the correct code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, that's a lot of `import`ed symbols at the module level.

I guess it works for you.
You might consider defining a `class`,
so these become `self.foo` object attributes
plus some class constants.

The `clock`, in particular, worries me.
`draw_markings()` side effects it.
Good manners suggests we should list it in the signature as an input parameter,
so the Gentle Reader has a heads up that it will be pretty important
during this function call.

Lots of module-level symbols *can* be a good thing,
but I worry that with too many it starts to encounter the coupling issues of
[global variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable).

```
    if i % 5 == 0:
```

Either this runs exactly once,
or there was an indentation copy-n-paste error
when submitting the source text to Code Review.

```
    elif i % 1 == 0:
```

No, please don't say `elif True:`,
prefer the simpler `else:`

Note that every single integer is congruent to zero mod one.

We see some
[repeated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
`penup` + `goto` code, hardly the end of the world.
Consider defaulting `size, color` to the "minutes" settings,
conditionally changing them to "hours" if we're on a multiple of five,
and then you're set up for a single `dot` call.

Often `for i ...` is the appropriate loop index identifier.
But here it's really representing the `minute`, so that
would have been a better name to choose.

Comment: I thank you so much for your reviews!